# How do I get the text value from a <select> in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core. I currently use the following `<select>` element in my view, within a `form`:

`<select asp-for="CarTypeId"></select>`

When I make the post I will only get the value for `Model.CarTypeId`.
However I have another field, `Model.CarType` which I want to give the value of the selected text in the `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another model property for this and set it during select event using jquery  or use formcollection.

Comment: See my comment on Munzer's post.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice, only the type id should be enough, and use it as a reference to the car type itself, shouldn't be one more field as you described, as this will be redundant.

Anyway the solution is adding a hidden field for CarType, and upon cartypeid change, update its value. 
something like this

```
$('#CarTypeId').on('change', function(){
// this will get the text of the selected option
var theText = $('#CarTypeId').find(":selected").text();
//Update value of the hidden field  
$('#CarType').val(theText);
});
```

Comment: In normal situations it would "bad" practice. In my own scenario there is a reason behind it.

Back to the question, using ```jQuery``` is already my current solution. But I would imagine there being a better solution.

Comment: better in which terms ?

Comment: Using a hidden field is usually not the best solution. I was hoping I overlooked some functionality built into ASP.NET Core as that would be the best solution.